# windowsのcmdでtensorflowがインポートできない問題

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

windowsのcmdでtensorflowとkerasを動かそうとしたのですが以下のようなエラーでtensorflowがインポートできないです。解決策などございましたらお願いします。

構成はWindows 10、Python 3.6.0、TensorFlow 2.3.1、Keras 2.4.3です。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import models
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "D:\zemi\re\keras-flask\train\myvenv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 48, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたプロシージャが見つかりません。
```

Comment: 承認のマークは付いていませんが、これらの記事あたりが該当するかもしれませんね。[Python protobuf "from google.protobuf.pyext import _message" - "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54154328/9014308), [ImportError: cannot import name '_message' from 'google.protobuf.pyext' (c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\pyext\__init__.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54733368/9014308) あるいはこれとか？ [Big Query - Local machine - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59073516/9014308)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
pythonのバージョンをpython3.6.8にしたところGPUでのwarningは出たものの推論は進めることができました！ありがとうございます！